# On an Facebook App, I have enabled the permission read_mailbox for users of my app. I am wondering how to access user's mailbox's?

Tags: facebook

so how can I read a users mailbox from the developer page?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the current user's mailbox by calling:

```
https://www.graph.facebook.com/me/inbox
```

where 'me' can be replaced with the current user's id.